# Why am I getting dynamic initialization not supported for __device__, __constant__, __shared__?

Tags: cuda, cmake

I don't understand why am I getting the error `dynamic initialization is not supported for __device__, __constant__, __shared__  variables` when compiling my code.
My code looks like

**wrapper.cu**

```
#include "../Params.hpp"

__constant__ Params cparams;

void wrapperFunction(uint& a)
{
   Params ab;
   a = 20;
}
```

**Params.hpp**

```
#include "Utils.hpp"

typedef struct Params
{
   vectorTypef a;
} Params;
```

**Utils.hpp**

```
#include "Vec2.hpp"

typedef unsigned int uint;
typedef Vec2<float> vectorTypef;
```

**Vec2.hpp**

```
template <typename T>
class Vec2
{
public:
   Vec2(){ x = 0.0; y = 0.0;}
   T x, y;
};
```

Building with cmake with the command

`CUDA_ADD_EXECUTABLE(test main.cpp cudasrc/wrapper.cu`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your `Params` struct is used in the `__constant__` memory definition of `cparams`.

Your `Params` struct contains an element `a` of type `vectorTypef` which is a typedef for the `Vec2` class for `float`.  This class has a default constructor, that is assigning elements ultimately of the `Params` struct.  This method of assigning data to a `__constant__` region is not legal either in device code or host code.

In device code it's not legal to modify a `__constant__` value at all.  In host code (which is what is in view here), `__constant__` values should be assigned using the appropriate API, i.e. `cudaMemcpyToSymbol`.  I would recommend that you assign these in your host code explicitly, rather than via a constructor.

So, one possible approach to fix this would be to change your default constructor to an empty one:

```
public:
   __host__ __device__ Vec2(){ }; // change this line
   T x, y;
```

(you could also just delete the empty default constructor line)

And, in wrapper.cu (perhaps in `wrapperFunction`), initialize your `Params`  `__constant__` struct:

```
Params hparams;
hparams.a.x = 0.0;
hparams.a.y = 0.0;
cudaMemcpyToSymbol(cparams, &hparams, sizeof(Params));
```

Comment: Could you provide an example? I think I didn't fully understand the idea.

Comment: added one possible fix as an example.

Comment: I tried it and I think there is missing something like `__host__ __code__` in the constructor, in order to have a device version of the vector type

Comment: Updated. (I had another error as well in setting `hparams` values.)  You could also just delete the empty default constructor.

Comment: Tried deleting the default constructor and the compilation complains about not finding it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problems as you and I found two ways to solve it.

1. define your struct in C-type, like this:

   ```
   typedef struct {} ClassName;
   ```
2. define both constructor and destructor as __device__ type, like this:

   ```
   struct ClassName{
   public:
       __device__ ClassName(){...}
       __device__ ~ClassName(){...}
   };
   ```